# Prestashop Module - Controller Field List - Filter/Search box not working / not showing filtered result

Tags: php, symfony, module, controller, prestashop

I'm working on a new module which allow to associate product to part of cars.

I'm facing a little issue, on every controllers I make, I use the fields_list, but when I'm using the search box, I doesn't filter the results as you can see on the following screenshot.

[image: image.png.dded8f4e1fdbedb4a1c131794dc1ab9c.png]

Here is my controller code :

```
//*** is to hide sensitive informations

<?php

require_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_ . '***Filter/classes/carBulbsAssociation.php');

class Admin***FilterCarBulbsAssociationController extends ModuleAdminController
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Base
        $this->bootstrap = true; // use Bootstrap CSS
        $this->table = '***filter_carbulb_association'; // SQL table name, will be prefixed with _DB_PREFIX_
        $this->identifier = 'id_***Filter_carbulb_association'; // SQL column to be used as primary key
        $this->className = 'CarBulbsAssociation'; // PHP class name
        $this->allow_export = true; // allow export in CSV, XLS..

        $this->addRowAction('edit');
        $this->addRowAction('view');
        $this->addRowAction('delete');
        $this->bulk_actions = array('delete' => array('text' => $this->l('Delete selected'), 'confirm' => $this->l('Delete selected items?'), 'icon' => 'icon-trash'));

        $this->_defaultOrderBy = 'a.id_***Filter_carbulb_association'; // the table alias is always `a`
        $this->_defaultOrderWay = 'ASC';
        $this->_select = 'a.id_***Filter_carbulb_association as `carBulbAssocID`,
        cbt.type_name as `bulbType`,
        prod.reference as `prodReference`,
        prodl.name as `prodName`,
        prod.id_product as  `prodID`';
        $this->_join = '
      LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . '***filter_carbulb_type` cbt ON a.id_***Filter_carbulb=cbt.id_***Filter_carbulb_type
      LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product` prod ON a.id_***Filter_product=prod.id_product
      LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_lang` prodl ON prod.id_product=prodl.id_product;
    ';
        $this->fields_list = array(
            'carBulbAssocID' => array('title' => 'Car Bulb ID'),
            'bulbType'  => array('title' => 'Bulb Type'),
            'prodReference' => array('title' => 'Product Reference'),
            'prodName' => array('title' => 'Product Name')
        );

        $products = Product::getProducts($this->context->language->id, 0, 0, 'name', 'ASC', false, true);

        $this->fields_form = array(
            'legend' => array(
                'title' => 'Edit Bulb Association'
            ),
            'input' => array(
                array('name' => 'bulbType', 'type'=>'text','label'=>'Bulb Type','required'=>true),
                array('name'=> 'prodID', 'label'=> 'Products', 'type'=>'select', 'required'=>true,
                'options'=>array( 'query'=> $products,
                    'id' => 'id_product',
                    'name' => 'name'
                ))
            ),
            'submit'=> array(
                'title'=> $this->l('Save')
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Here is my class :

```
//**** is to hide sensitive informations

<?php

class CarBulbsAssociation extends ObjectModel{

    public $id_***Filter_carbulb_association;
    public $id_***Filter_carbulb;
    public $id_***Filter_product;

    public static $definition = array(
        'table'=> '***filter_carbulb_association',
        'primary' => 'id_***Filter_carbulb_association',
        'fields'=> array(
            'id_***Filter_carbulb_association' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate'=> 'isUnsignedInt', 'required'=> true ),
            'id_***Filter_carbulb' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate'=> 'isUnsignedInt', 'required'=> true ),
            'id_***Filter_product' => array('type' => self::TYPE_INT, 'validate'=> 'isUnsignedInt', 'required'=> true ),
        )
        );
}

?>
```

My class seems to be well define, I don't have any issues with that, I think that the issue is from :

```
'a.id_***Filter_carbulb_association as `carBulbAssocID`,
        cbt.type_name as `bulbType`,
        prod.reference as `prodReference`,
        prodl.name as `prodName`,
        prod.id_product as  `prodID`';
```

In cause of the aliases, but after trying without aliases, I've got the same issue so I don't really know, if anybody already faced the same issue or similar, let me know !

Here is the SQL QUERY  :

```
`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.* , a.id_***Filter_carbrand as `modelBrandID`, a.id_***Filter_carmodel as `modelID`, a.name as `carModelName`, a.category_id as `modelCatId`, cb.name as `carBrand`, kit.auxiliary_indicator , kit.daytime_running_light , kit.fog_light , kit.front_indicator , kit.high_beam , kit.license_plate, kit.low_beam, kit.parking_light, kit.rear_indicator , kit.rear_fog_light , kit.reversing_light , kit.side_indicator , kit.stoplight , kit.taillight FROM `miib_***filter_carmodel` a LEFT JOIN `miib_***filter_carbulb_kit` kit ON kit.id_***Filter_carmodel=a.id_***Filter_carmodel LEFT JOIN `miib_***filter_carbrand` cb ON cb.id_***Filter_carbrand=a.id_***Filter_carbrand; WHERE 1 AND cb.`name` LIKE '%Abarth%' ORDER BY a.`id_***Filter_carbrand` ASC LIMIT 0, 50
`
```

Comment: You are missing 'search' => true in fields_form input

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer @FranCerezo ! I'm trying to allow search in my fields list and not in my fields form, so does this code in fields form will work fields list ?